# Tensorflow session.run( ) doesn't work with HUG

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, hug

I am struggling with tensorflow `session.run()` with hug in python.
If I run `session.run()` without HUG for predicting, It is fine.
But, if I run this on hug, it doesn't make any result (even any error).

Did anyone come across such scenario? 
Please help me.

My environments:

- tensorflow version 1.2.1
- hug 2.3.0
- python version 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the cause of your problem, but perhaps it might be related to the fact `hug` is a sever, and thus, it has some asynchronous code somewhere. Maybe what is happening is, because `hug` is trying to handle the request, it starts the session but doesn't wait for it to run.

Again, I don't know if this is the root cause or not, or even if this scenario even makes sense.

What I can suggest though, based on the little experience I had with `Tensorflow`, is to set up a different architecture.

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do now is, you want to send a request to the hug api server, pick up the data from that request and feed it to a `Tensorflow` session. You want to wait for `Tensorflow` to predict something and return that prediction to the user that make the request.

I would approach this problem in a slightly different way. I would have the client establish a [`websockets`](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) connection. The client would use this connection to send data to the server. Upon receiving this data, the server would place it in a [message queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue). You can use a real message queue like [RabbitMq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) but to be honest, if you don't have a production quality app, you might as well just use `redis` or even `mongo` as a message queue. The messages in this queue would be picked up by a worker process, one running `Tensoflow` and would use the data in the messages to perform a prediction. Upon performing the prediction, the data would be placed in a different queue and be picked up by the server. The server would then return through the `websocket` the prediction to the client.

The major thing you solve with this approach is separating the `api` server from the `Tensorflow` worker. This will allow you to debug and test each part independently. More over, you will not be clogging your server by waiting for `Tensorflow`. The server will essentially act as a scheduler and the worker will work. When it finishes, it just returns the result.

I hope this will help you and sorry again if my suggestion regarding the possible root cause is wrong.